# Code Optimization to check some items of checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq

Consider following code snippet

List orderList ; // This list is pre-populated

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in OrdersChoiceList.Items) // OrdersChoiceList is of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList
{
     foreach (Order o in orderList)
     {
           if (item.id == o.id)
           {
               item.Selected = scopeComputer.SelectedBox;
               break;
           }
     }
}
```

There are thousands of item in the list, hence these loops are time consuming. How we can optimze it?

Also how can we do the same stuff with LINQ. I tried using join operation but not able to set the value of "Selected" variable based on "SelectedBox". For now I hardocoded the value in select clause to "true", how can we pass & use SelectedBox value in select clause

```
                 var v = (from c in ComputersChoiceList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                    join s in scopeComputers on c.Text equals s.CName
                                        select c).Select(x=>x.Selected = true);
```

Comment: Can we use LINQ here ?

Comment: Maybe if(OrdersChoiceList.Items.Select(i => i.id).Intersect( orderList.Select(i => i.id) ).Any()) ...

Comment: I _feel_ like it shouldn't take long to iterate even "thousands of items" to update their selected state. I _feel_ like the "time consuming" aspect is the GUI layer updating itself. EDIT: Oh, maybe not. Didn't pick up on the nested foreach loop here. Definitely change your `orderList` to be a lookup table of some sort rather than re-iterating it time after time after time for each and every ListItem.

Comment: Are there thousands of items in both lists? Or thousands in one list and far fewer in the other list?

Comment: both the list has large items.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to eliminate the nested iteration. As you state, both lists have a large set of items. If they both have 5,000 items, then you're looking at 25,000,000 iterations in the worst case.

There's no need to continually re-iterate `orderList` for every single `ListItem`. Instead create an ID lookup so you have fast O(1) lookups for each ID. Not sure what work is involved hitting `scopeComputer.SelectedBox`, but that may as well be resolved once outside the loop as well.

```
bool selectedState = scopeComputer.SelectedBox;
HashSet<int> orderIDs = new HashSet<int>(orders.Select(o => o.id));

foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in OrdersChoiceList.Items)
{
    if (orderIDs.Contains(item.id))
        item.Selected = selectedState;
}
```

Using a `HashSet` lookup, you're now really only iterating 5,000 times plus a super-fast lookup.

EDIT: From what I can tell, there's no `id` property on `ListItem`, but I'm assuming that the code you've posted is condensed for brevity, but largely representative of your overall process. I'll keep my code API/usage to match what you have there; I'm assuming it's translatable back to your specific implementation.

EDIT: Based on your edited question, I *think* you're doing yet *another* lookup/iteration on retrieving the `scopeComputer` reference. Similarly, you can make another lookup for this:

```
HashSet<int> orderIDs = new HashSet<int>(orders.Select(o => o.id));
Dictionary<string, bool> scopeComputersSelectedState = 
    scopeComputers.ToDictionary(s => s.CName, s => s.Selected);

foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in OrdersChoiceList.Items)
{
    if (orderIDs.Contains(item.id))
        item.Selected = scopeComputersSelectedState[item.Text];
}
```

Again, not sure on the exact types/usage you have. You *could* also condense this down with a single LINQ query, but I don't think (performance speaking) you will see much of a improvement. I'm also *assuming* that there is a matching `ScopeComputer` for every `ListItem.Text` entry otherwise you'll get an exception when accessing `scopeComputersSelectedState[item.Text]`. If not, then it should be a trivial exercise for you to change it to perform a `TryGetValue` lookup instead.